# Apache+Flask not recognizing wsgi file

Tags: python, apache, flask, centos7

Running Anaconda python not the global python that comes with CentOS 7, I have installed and tested Flask locally and it works fine.

```
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$ python __init__.py
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$ curl localhost:5000
Hello, I love Flask!
```

When I try to run it under apache, as follows, I get the error at the end. I think the problem is that apache is trying to run the global python and not Anaconda python which is where I installed Flask. If true, I don't want to mess with the path that the system uses for the global python as it can cause problems. Not sure how to tell the system in this case to use Anaconda python:

```
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$ which python
~/anaconda2/bin/python
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$
```

My application is as follows:

File: `hello.py`

```
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$ more hello.py
import sys
import logging
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$
```

File: `__init__.py`

```
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$ more __init__.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, I love Flask!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$
```

My directory structure is as follows.

```
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$ pwd
/var/www/FlaskApp
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Jan 19 03:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root   root   4096 Jan 19 02:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 apache apache 4096 Jan 19 02:36 FlaskApp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache  164 Jan 19 02:32 hello.conf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache  107 Jan 19 03:21 hello.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache  164 Jan 19 02:25 hello.wsgi
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$ cd FlaskApp/
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 4 apache apache 4096 Jan 19 02:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Jan 19 03:21 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  150 Jan 19 02:35 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  449 Jan 19 02:36 __init__.pyc
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Jan 19 02:01 static
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Jan 19 02:01 templates
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$
```

My apache .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias mywebsite-ed.com
    ServerAdmin me@mywebsite.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/hello.py
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I get this error:

```
[idf@node3 FlaskApp]$ sudo tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
[sudo] password for idf: 
[Thu Jan 19 03:23:46.918092 2017] [:error] [pid 4305] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:54062] mod_wsgi (pid=4305): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/hello.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jan 19 03:23:46.918161 2017] [:error] [pid 4305] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:54062] mod_wsgi (pid=4305): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/hello.py'.
[Thu Jan 19 03:23:46.918225 2017] [:error] [pid 4305] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:54062] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jan 19 03:23:46.918291 2017] [:error] [pid 4305] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:54062]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/hello.py", line 5, in <module>
[Thu Jan 19 03:23:46.918546 2017] [:error] [pid 4305] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:54062]     from FlaskApp import app as application
[Thu Jan 19 03:23:46.918595 2017] [:error] [pid 4305] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:54062]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Thu Jan 19 03:23:46.918671 2017] [:error] [pid 4305] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:54062]     from flask import Flask
[Thu Jan 19 03:23:46.918734 2017] [:error] [pid 4305] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:54062] ImportError: No module named flask
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall system mod_wsgi package and then compile mod_wsgi from source code against Anaconda Python. Suggest you use method shown at:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

whereby you `pip install` it into the Anaconda Python environment and use:

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

to output the lines you should add to your Apache configuration to load the mod_wsgi module and ensure that Anaconda Python distribution is correctly found.